# let $f(x)=x^3-2x+4$ without finding them, explain why we know there must be values c1, c2, c3 $\ldots$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=x^3-2x+4$ without finding them, explain why we know there must be values $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $f(c_1)=\pi$, $f(c_2)=-\sqrt 7$, $f(c_3)=1,000,000$ . I am not sure how to attack this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jimmy R's reasoning.

For example: Easy to check that $f(-1,000,000) < -2,000,000$ and $f(1,000,000) > 2,000,000$. Furthermore, $f$ is continuous. Thus as $1,000,000$ satisfies $f(-1,000,000) < -2,000,000 < 1,000,000 < 2,000,000 < f(1,000,000)$, the Intermediate Value Theorem says that there is an $x$ such that $f(x)$ is exactly $1,000,000$.

Finish the rest in the same fashion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the limits of $f(x)$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. Then use that $f(x)$ is continuous, to infer that $f$ attains all the values between these limits.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\mathbb R)$ is an intervall. We have $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, hence $f( \mathbb R)= \mathbb R.$

Can you take it from here ?